# Regular expression to match and extract parts from an URL in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to get artifactory instance name, repository name and artifact names into 3 variables,  from the complete artifact URL like below ones.

`"https://artifactory.intuit.veg.com:443/artifactory/annual-budget-local/manifests-approved/1.0.0/annual-chart/po09ij/annual-f3c.tgz"`

`"https://artifactory.skopeo.marvel.org/artifactory/bulletins_virtual/manifests-approved/po09ij/annual-f3c.tgz"`

artifactory instance's being -> `artifactory.intuit.veg.com` and `artifactory.skopeo.marvel.org`

repository name being -> `annual-budget-local` and `bulletins_virtual`

artifact names -> `manifests-approved/1.0.0/annual-chart/po09ij/annual-f3c.tgz` and `manifests-approved/po09ij/annual-f3c.tgz`

I can make use of `split` with multiple combinations but I would like to understand how efficiently I can use the Python `regex` here, any guidance will be really useful.

Should I be matching strings before and after the word `artifactory` and do an additional split operation to get the `artifact name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite similar to Aymen Azouis solution with small optimizations.

1. using `regex` library which imho should be preferred over `re`
2. option to detect `http://` as well as `https://`
3. possessive quantifiers

```
(?x)
^                                  # start of pattern
https?                             # http with an optional s
://
(?P<artifactory_instance>[^/:]++)  # capture everything up to the next ":" or "/"
(?::\d++)?                         # if you encounter a port match it (optional)
/artifactory/
(?P<repository>[^/]++)             # match repository by capturing everything up to next "/"
/
(?P<artifact_names>.++)            # match the rest of URL to artifact names
$
```

On regex101 (https://regex101.com/r/7Ww4ui/1) the possessive quantifiers are omitted, as the `re` module does not handle them (which is what is implemented on rexex101).

Or as executable code:

```
import regex 

def extract_artifactory_data(url):
    pattern = r"^https?://(?P<artifactory_instance>[^/:]++)(?::\d++)?/artifactory/(?P<repository>[^/]++)/(?P<artifact_names>.++)$"
    match = regex.match(pattern, url)
    
    if not match:
        return None
    
    return match.group("artifactory_instance"), match.group("repository"), match.group("artifact_names")

url1 = "https://artifactory.intuit.veg.com:443/artifactory/annual-budget-local/manifests-approved/1.0.0/annual-chart/po09ij/annual-f3c.tgz"
url2 = "https://artifactory.skopeo.marvel.org/artifactory/bulletins_virtual/manifests-approved/po09ij/annual-f3c.tgz"

instance1, repo1, artifact1 = extract_artifactory_data(url1)
instance2, repo2, artifact2 = extract_artifactory_data(url2)

print(instance1, repo1, artifact1)
print(instance2, repo2, artifact2)
```

Comment: Great, appreciate your input here !! 
Could you please elaborate the regex syntax as well :) Thanks !

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the details..

Comment: If you concur with the answer consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

Just to point out, there is also the `urllib.parse` module, which is meant for splitting URLs. No reason to re-invent the wheel.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

urls = [ "https://artifactory.intuit.veg.com:443/artifactory/annual-budget-local/manifests-approved/1.0.0/annual-chart/po09ij/annual-f3c.tgz", "https://artifactory.skopeo.marvel.org/artifactory/bulletins_virtual/manifests-approved/po09ij/annual-f3c.tgz"]

for url in urls:
    o = urlparse(url)
    instance, repo = o.hostname, o.path.split('/')[2]
    print(instance, repo)
```

Answer (score 2):

tyr this :

```py
import re

def extract_artifactory_data(url):
    pattern = r"https://(?P<instance>[^:/]+)(?::\d+)?/artifactory/(?P<repo>[^/]+)/(?P<artifact>.+)"
    match = re.match(pattern, url)
    
    if not match:
        return None
    
    return match.group("instance"), match.group("repo"), match.group("artifact")

url1 = "https://artifactory.intuit.veg.com:443/artifactory/annual-budget-local/manifests-approved/1.0.0/annual-chart/po09ij/annual-f3c.tgz"
url2 = "https://artifactory.skopeo.marvel.org/artifactory/bulletins_virtual/manifests-approved/po09ij/annual-f3c.tgz"

instance1, repo1, artifact1 = extract_artifactory_data(url1)
instance2, repo2, artifact2 = extract_artifactory_data(url2)

print(instance1, repo1, artifact1)
print(instance2, repo2, artifact2)
```

Comment: Bit of explanation please :) ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example to code to split URLs as you described:

```
import re

# Sample URLs
urls = [
    "https://artifactory.intuit.veg.com:443/artifactory/annual-budget-local/manifests-approved/1.0.0/annual-chart/po09ij/annual-f3c.tgz",
    "https://artifactory.skopeo.marvel.org/artifactory/bulletins_virtual/manifests-approved/po09ij/annual-f3c.tgz"
]

for url in urls:
    match = re.search(r'https://([^/]+).+?/([^/]+)/(.+)$', url)
    if match:
        instance_name, repository_name, artifact_name = match.groups()
    else:
        instance_name, repository_name, artifact_name = "N/A", "N/A", "N/A"

    print("Artifactory Instance:", instance_name)
    print("Repository Name:", repository_name)
    print("Artifact Name:", artifact_name)
```

For the regular expression **https://([^/]+).+?/([^/]+)/(.+)$** :

**https://**: This part of the pattern matches the literal characters "https://" at the beginning of the URL.

**([^/]+)**: This is a capturing group that matches one or more characters that are not a forward slash (/). It's enclosed in parentheses, which means the matched content will be captured and can be extracted later.

**.+?/**: This part of the pattern matches one or more characters (.+?) followed by a forward slash (/). The .+? is a non-greedy match, which means it will match as few characters as possible while still allowing the rest of the pattern to match.

**([^/]+)**: Similar to the first capturing group, this matches one or more characters that are not a forward slash and captures them.

**(.+)$**: This part of the pattern matches one or more characters followed by the end of the line ($) and captures them. This allows it to capture everything that follows the second capturing group until the end of the URL.

The search function matches instance_name, repository_name and artifact_name groups from the input string by using the regular expression.